# Unable to filter data per user's inputs using eventReactive() function in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, radar-chart, shiny-reactivity

I'm building my first app in Shiny and I've been meaning to get a better idea about reactivity. I have gone through the tutorials on http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/. I'm working on a tennis-related dataset and wanting to create a radarchart using the package 'radarchart'. I'm able to render the radio buttons and select input box successfully using reactive expressions.

However, upon clicking the 'Go!' button, the console shows the following error: "Error in filter_impl: incorrect length (0), expecting: 27". No error shows up in the app itself though, there's just no rendering on clicking the 'Go!' button.

Upon debugging, I see that this error occurs when I'm trying to filter data using the user's selection of input values(lines 60-63 in server.R). My main concern is filtering the data as per the user's selection, I'm unable to do that in any way. I've tried to use eventReactive(), observe() as well as reactiveValues() functions too without any success. I've wrapped the renderChartJSRadar function within the eventReactive function, but I'm not quite sure if that's the right way to go about it.

I'm confused as to how the reactivity in this case should work and what I'm missing to make it work. The code is as shown below. I'd really appreciate any kind of help.

**ui.R**

```
library(xlsx)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
source("chart.R")
library(radarchart)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

          titlePanel("Match Radar Chart"),

          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
              selectInput("var", 
                         label = "Choose a tournament",
                         choices = tour,
                         selected = "Auckland"),

              uiOutput("radioButtons"),
              uiOutput("selectControls"),
              actionButton("update", "Go!")
              ),

              mainPanel(
                 chartJSRadarOutput("radarChart", width = "450", height = "300")
              )
        )
 ))
```

**server.R**

```
library(xlsx)
library(dplyr)
library(radarchart)
library(data.table)
source("chart.R")
library(shiny)
library(grDevices)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$radioButtons <- renderUI({
               dataInput <- reactive({input$var})
               z <- dataInput()
               buttons <- numrounds(z)
               radioButtons("button", "Select a round: ", choices = buttons, inline = FALSE)
      })

    output$selectControls <- renderUI({
               dataInput <- reactive({input$var})
               z <- dataInput()
               dataInput1 <- reactive({input$button})
               y <- dataInput1()
               winner <- mydata %>%
                      filter(tourney_name == z) %>%
                      filter(round == y) %>%
                      select(winner_name) %>%
                      sapply(as.character) %>%
                      as.vector()

               loser <- mydata %>%
                      filter(tourney_name == z) %>%
                      filter(round == y) %>%
                      select(loser_name) %>%
                      sapply(as.character) %>%
                      as.vector()

               players <- c(winner, loser)

               selectInput("select", "Select a match: ", choices = players, selected = 1, multiple = FALSE)

     })    

          output$radarChart <- eventReactive(input$update, {
          renderChartJSRadar({
          dataInput1 <- reactive({input$var})
          z <- dataInput1()
          dataInput2 <- reactive({input$button})
          y <- dataInput2()
          dataInput3 <- reactive({input$select})
          x <- dataInput3()
          match <- mydata %>%
              filter(tourney_name == z) %>%
              filter(round == y) %>%
              filter(winner_name == x)

          scoresw <- vector()
          scoresl <- vector()
          for(j in 25:33) {
                  scoresw <- c(scoresw, match()[j])
          }
          for(j in 34:42) {
                  scoresl <- c(scoresl, match()[j])
          }

          scores <- list(winner = scoresw, loser = scoresl)
          labs <- c("Aces", "Double Faults", "Service points", "1st Service In", "1st Service won", "2nd Service won", "Service games", "Break points saved", "Break points faced")
          c <- grDevices::col2rgb(c("green", "red"))

          chartJSRadar(scores = scores, labs = labs, labelSize = 15, colMatrix = c)
     })
  })

 })
```

**chart.R**

```
mydata <- read.csv("Match Radar/Data/atp_matches_2014_edited.csv", header = TRUE)
tour <- unique(data$tourney_name)


 numrounds <- function(z) {
   for(i in 1:64) {
     rounds <- mydata %>%
       filter(tourney_name == z) %>%
       summarise(number = n_distinct(round))

     if(rounds == 3){
         buttons <- c("RR", "SF", "F")
     }
     else if(rounds == 5){
         buttons <- c("R32", "R16", "QF", "SF", "F")
     }
     else if(rounds == 6){
         buttons <- c("R64", "R32", "R16", "QF", "SF", "F")
     }
     else {
         buttons <- c("R128", "R64", "R32", "R16", "QF", "SF", "F")
     }
   }
   buttons
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your app in a single file for debugging simplicity.

The menus display correctly: the shiny part should work.  The basic idea is that the input variables are already reactive, so to build a reactive function out of them is redundant (at least in this case).

In `renderChartJSRadar` z,y and x are initialised correctly (once the initial, NULL cases are discarded). Also `renderChartJSRadar` is already reactive, but as it is "eagerly reactive" it starts when the other values are not set, hence the filtering for NULL.

In `renderChartJSRadar` there is debugging to do in the R logic that calculate the score.  Currently there is an error: unfortunately I cannot help as I cannot tell what you want to achieve - and I don't play tennis :)

```
library(xlsx)
library(dplyr)
library(radarchart)
# library(data.table)
# source("chart.R")
library(shiny)
library(grDevices)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

mydata <- read.csv("./data/atp_matches_2014.csv", header = TRUE)
tour <- unique(mydata$tourney_name)

numrounds <- function(z) {
  for(i in 1:64) {
    rounds <- mydata %>%
      filter(tourney_name == z) %>%
      summarise(number = n_distinct(round))

    if(rounds == 3){
      buttons <- c("RR", "SF", "F")
    }
    else if(rounds == 5){
      buttons <- c("R32", "R16", "QF", "SF", "F")
    }
    else if(rounds == 6){
      buttons <- c("R64", "R32", "R16", "QF", "SF", "F")
    }
    else {
      buttons <- c("R128", "R64", "R32", "R16", "QF", "SF", "F")
    }
  }
  return(buttons)
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Match Radar Chart"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("var", 
                  label = "Choose a tournament",
                  choices = tour,
                  selected = "Auckland"),

      uiOutput("radioButtons"),
      uiOutput("selectControls"),
      actionButton("update", "Go!")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      chartJSRadarOutput("radarChart", width = "450", height = "300")
    )
  )
)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

server <-  function(input, output, session){
  session$onSessionEnded({  stopApp  }) 

  output$radioButtons <- renderUI({
    # dataInput <- reactive({input$var})

    z <- input$var
    buttons <- numrounds(z)
    radioButtons("button", "Select a round: ", choices = buttons, inline = FALSE)
  })

  output$selectControls <- renderUI({

    # dataInput <- reactive({input$var})
    z <- input$var
    # dataInput1 <- reactive({input$button})
    y <- input$button #dataInput1()
    winner <- mydata %>%
      filter(tourney_name == z) %>%
      filter(round == y) %>%
      select(winner_name) %>%
      sapply(as.character) %>%
      as.vector()

    loser <- mydata %>%
      filter(tourney_name == z) %>%
      filter(round == y) %>%
      select(loser_name) %>%
      sapply(as.character) %>%
      as.vector()

    players <- c(winner, loser)

    selectInput("select", "Select a match: ", choices = players, selected = 1, multiple = FALSE)

  })    

  output$radarChart <- renderChartJSRadar({
    # browser()
      if(is.null(input$button )) return()
      if(is.null(input$select )) return()
      # dataInput1 <- reactive({input$var})
      z <- input$var # dataInput1()
      # dataInput2 <- reactive({input$button})
      y <- input$button # dataInput2()
      # dataInput3 <- reactive({input$select})
      x <- input$select # dataInput3()
      match <- mydata %>%
        filter(tourney_name == z) %>%
        filter(round == y) %>%
        filter(winner_name == x)

      scoresw <- vector()
      scoresl <- vector()
      for(j in 25:33) {
        scoresw <- c(scoresw, match()[j])
      }
      for(j in 34:42) {
        scoresl <- c(scoresl, match()[j])
      }

      scores <- list(winner = scoresw, loser = scoresl)
      labs <- c("Aces", "Double Faults", "Service points", "1st Service In", "1st Service won", "2nd Service won", "Service games", "Break points saved", "Break points faced")
      c <- grDevices::col2rgb(c("green", "red"))

      chartJSRadar(scores = scores, labs = labs, labelSize = 15, colMatrix = c)

  })

}
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As far as preventing the radar chart to be drawn every time the user changes one of the three inputs, this is possible using `isolate`.

For example (code not tested, but it should work :) )

```
output$radarChart <- renderChartJSRadar({
      if(is.null(input$button )) return()
      isolate({
           if(is.null(input$select )) return()
           z <- input$var # dataInput1()
           y <- input$button # dataInput2()
           x <- input$select # dataInput3()
      })
```

Or something very similar.  Take for example `input$var`.  As it is within `isolate`, any change by the user will not trigger the execution of `renderChartJSRadar`. In the code above only changes to input$button trigger the execution of `renderChartJSRadar`.

Comment: I believe the problem persists because the 'scores' variable depends on 'scoresw' and 'scoresl', which in turn depend on the reactive variable 'match()'. I tried by converting into 'scoresw()', 'scoresl()' and 'scores()' but without success. There might be an issue with initializing the vectors 'scoresw' and 'scoresl'. I have tried to initialize 'scoresw' and 'scoresl' as empty vectors. The 'match' variable changes every time the user changes his inputs. Do you have any idea how to incorporate this functionality to make my 'scores' variable work? Thank you.

Comment: Also, thanks for removing redundant elements in the code and adding the filtering for NULL in case of renderchartJSRadar, I totally missed that. I tried running it and I see that somehow the 'scores' variable is not being computed correctly.

Comment: I really appreciate your inputs Enzo, I was able to make it work by tweaking the variable 'match' a little bit. It turns out that it isn't reactive, so I don't need to use 'match()', and don't need to worry about all the consequent reactivity. I had one last question(although it isn't too pressing) - how could I tweak my code to update the chart only on clicking the 'Go!' button. In my working code, it turns out that the chart gets updated everytime I change either of the three inputs. What should I do if I want to update it only when the user clicks on the 'Go!' button? Thanks again!

Comment: I've added some lines of code above to limit the execution of `renderChartJSRadar` only when the button is pressed.  If you think my answer respond to your question, please accept it as a solution. Thanks

Comment: It sure does and it clarified my concepts regarding using isolate() too. Thank you so much for your help, really appreciate it.